# How to set up an function with increasing coefficients?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to set something up with the end results of:

```
sum = c1x^1 + c2 x^2 + c3 x^3 ... etc
```

but I'm struggling to set up the increasing power while keeping the cn. This is what I've managed to do so far:

```
element1 [x_, a_, c_] = c * x^a
kvar[k_Integer] :=  ToExpression@Map[StringJoin[#, ToString[k]] &, {"c"}]
gmodel[n_Integer] := Sum[element1[x, Sequence @@ n,  Sequence @@ kvar[i]], {i, 1, n}]
```

But that just gives the output of

```
gmodel[3] = c1 x^3 + c2 x^3 + c3 x^3
```

when I want

```
gmodel[3] = c1 x + c2 x^2 + c3 x^3
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What about `gmodel[n_] := Sum[Indexed[c, i] x^i, {i, 1, n}]`?

Comment: If you are comfortable with and you want to use `ToString` and `ToExpression` then what about `gmodel[n_]:=Sum[ToExpression["c"<>ToString[i]<>"*x^"<>ToString[i]],{i,1,n}];
gmodel[3]`

Comment: @Bill, I'd use `Symbol[]` + `IntegerString[]` instead: `Sum[Symbol["c" <> IntegerString[k]] x^k, {k, 3}]`.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less I recognize that people have strong feelings on this topic, thus I carefully included the "If that is what he wanted to do..." disclaimer.

Comment: You just need to simplify your code a little in the 3rd line to `Sum[ element1[x, i, kvar[i]], {i, n}]`

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are twisting and turning in order to keep a naming convention. Why not index the c's as an array? Then the code becomes trivial:

```
n = 5;
cArray = Array[c, n];
Total[cArray x^Range[n]]

x c[1] + x^2 c[2] + x^3 c[3] + x^4 c[4] + x^5 c[5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FromDigits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html) as follows:

```
coeffs = {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5};

ExpandAll @ FromDigits[Reverse[Prepend[coeffs, 0]], x]
```

> c1 x + c2 x^2 + c3 x^3 + c4 x^4 + c5 x^5

```
ClearAll[gmodel]
gmodel[n_] := Module[{cs = Reverse @ Prepend[Symbol["c" <> ToString @ #] & /@ Range[n], 0]}, 
  ExpandAll @ FromDigits[cs, x]]

gmodel[6]
```

> c1 x + c2 x^2 + c3 x^3 + c4 x^4 + c5 x^5 + c6 x^6

Alternatively, using `Dot`:

```
ClearAll[gmodel2]
gmodel2[n_] := Module[{cs =Array[Symbol["c" <> ToString @ #] &, n], xs = x^Range[n]}, cs.xs]
gmodel2[6]
```

> c1 x + c2 x^2 + c3 x^3 + c4 x^4 + c5 x^5 + c6 x^6

If you wish to use `Sum`:

```
ClearAll[gmodel0]
gmodel0[n_] := Module[{cs = Array[Symbol["c" <> ToString@#] &, n]}, Sum[cs[[i]] x^i, {i, n}]]
gmodel0[6]
```

> c1 x + c2 x^2 + c3 x^3 + c4 x^4 + c5 x^5 + c6 x^6

**Update:** A function that takes different arguments:

```
ClearAll[gmodel0]
gmodel0[n_, v_: c] := Module[{cs = Array[Symbol[ToString[v] <> ToString@#] &, n]}, 
  Sum[cs[[i]] x^i, {i, n}]]
gmodel0[c_List] := Sum[c[[i]] x^i, {i, Length@c}]

gmodel0[5]
```

> c1 x + c2 x^2 + c3 x^3 + c4 x^4 + c5 x^5

```
gmodel0[5, a]
```

> a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4 + a5 x^5

```
gmodel0[{b1, b2, b3}]
```

> b1 x + b2 x^2 + b3 x^3

Comment: I think I'll use the last one. If I also need gmodel to be a function of c1, c2 etc, how would I implement that?

Comment: @Squidward, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been very helpful!

Comment: @Squidward, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.